Submit the WooCommerce login form via Ajax
I've registered users on my site and require them to reset their passwords before logging in. I've added a user meta field to check if they've already changed their password. If they have, they can log in as usual; if not, they see a pop-up prompting them to reset their password. The pop-up appears correctly, but when users who have already changed their password submit the form via AJAX, the form is submitted, but they aren't logged in. I suspect it might be a security issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
`;(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form.woocommerce-form.woocommerce-form-login').on('submit', function(e) {
            var form = $(this);
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting by default

            var username = $('#username').val(); 
            var password = $('#password').val(); 

            // Check if the user needs to reset the password
            $.ajax({
                url: passwordResetData.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'check_is_pass_changed_status',
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    form_data: form.serialize() // Serialize the form data
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success && response.data.show_popup) {
                        $('#password-reset-modal').fadeIn();
                    } else if (response.success) {
                        form.submit(); // Submit the form programmatically
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error: " + (response.data.message || 'Unknown error.'));
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('AJAX Error:', status, error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);`

When i am submiting the form, user should login.

Could you please share what message you are getting on the browser console while we are submitted the form, because with that message we are able to troubleshoot further.

There was no error in the console, it was just the user couldn't log in.  I have changed the approach to solve this. Thanks
